# NetWorker: Frequent errors in log "waiting for # writable volume(s) to backup pool 'Default' disk(s) on

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, emc

Working on a new NetWorker 7.6.3/DataDomain disk-to-disk-to-remote-disk backup system, there are frequent errors in the log:

> Media alert event: Waiting for 1 writable volume(s) to backup pool 'Default' disk(s) on

Things that vary in the errors:

- They seem to be grouped in sets of four, one labeled "Media alert event", another "Media critical event", then "Media request event", and finally "Media waiting event".
- Sometimes it is waiting for 1, sometimes 2, and sometimes 0 writable volume(s).

That backup pool is always Default, and the server is always the NetWorker server in our domain.

After a while there is a "Media event cleared" event recorded in the log.

This is still a small test setup with only a few clients and servers being backed up through the system. They are all configured to backup through specific groups, to specific pools, on specific volumes, and Default is not being used at all.

What is causing this error and how do I resolve it?

Searching elsewhere it appear to be related to Parallelism. The clients are all configured to Parallelism values of 2, and the Pools are all have Max Parallelism values of 0 which should mean unlimited, correct?

The clients are currently all Windows Server 2008 and Windows 7, 64bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is still a bit confusing but it's resolved.

The base issue was that there were no volumes assigned to the default pool. Just like the error said.

But...

None of the groups and none of the pools and none of the clients were configured to backup to the default pool. So why it was complaining is still beyond me.

The issue went away after I rebuilt the NetWorker server and setup entirely.

Answer (score 0):

easy, the indexes probably would have been saved to default

try redirecting *:index or index:* & bootstrap to another pool

Comment: So the indexes are not stored with the pools their backups are sent to? And what commands or tools would I use to redirect the indexes and/or bootstraps?